# Pre filled value in facebook lead form

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, ads

Can we add a pre-filled field in a Facebook lead form.
For example, if we are using a carousel from a vehicle catalog, can we add vehicle.price in the lead form?
So that user do not have to enter the value. The form should pick the price value from the catalog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add pre-filled data to forms based on your preferences:
According to facebook's documentation,
*To make your lead ad instant forms easier to complete, you can add prefilled fields to your instant form so that people don't need to manually add answers to your questions.*

Note:
People can edit any prefilled info except for their date of birth.
If someone's information (ex: email, phone) isn't already on their Facebook or Instagram profile, they'll be prompted to add the fields manually before submitting the instant form.
If you're running your lead ads on Instagram, keep in mind that Instagram currently only supports prefilled fields for the following: Email, Full name, Phone number and Gender.
These are the available fields that can be marked as prefill while creating lead ads instant forms.

However, there are a few specifications as to the field types allowed here.
[Check out facebook's form documentation for a full list of specific field types here](https://web.facebook.com/business/help/774623835981457?id=735435806665862)

Also, you can refer to this [facebook's documentation for info on how to set up custom lead questions](https://web.facebook.com/business/help/774623835981457?id=735435806665862)